# How to change the color of the interactive zoom rectangle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple interactive plot. When I click on the magnifying glass button I can draw a rectangle to do interactive zooming. You can see the dotted rectangle in the image below.

[image]

However, when I use white grid on a dark background (with `plt.style.use('dark_background')`), the zoom rectangle is barely visible. It is still there but black on a largely black plot.

[image]

For completeness, the plots where generated with Matplotlib 3.1.3 as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('dark_background')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

data = 2.5 * np.random.randn(400) + 3
ax.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

So my question therefore is: how can I change the color of the zoom rectangle?

Comment: From looking through the code base, it seems that the class/method that would need to be monkey-patched is `RubberbandXx.draw_rubberband`, where `Xx` depends on the backend used: [e.g. for TkAgg, this is is `RubberbandTk`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7b14917a18505bf0ffac941c8745c328532473d2/lib/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py#L664), etc. However, I can't figure out how to pass a colour argument to `self.figure.canvas._tkcanvas.create_rectangle`, which is the function called by `draw_rubberband`.

Comment: This issue is fixed in release 3.3.1. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what backend you're using there is no (at least I don't know a)  universal solution. As stated in the comments this can be achieved only with monkey-patching. Here is my attempt using Qt5 backend. Note that you need to have PyQt5 installed too in order to make this work.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import FigureCanvasQT

# extending the original FigureCanvasQT class

class NewFigureCanvasQT(FigureCanvasQT):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def drawRectangle(self, rect):
        # Draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter.  _draw_rect_callback needs
        # to be called at the end of paintEvent.
        if rect is not None:
            def _draw_rect_callback(painter):
                pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 1 / self._dpi_ratio, # <-- change the color here
                                 QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
                painter.setPen(pen)
                painter.drawRect(*(pt / self._dpi_ratio for pt in rect))
        else:
            def _draw_rect_callback(painter):
                return
        self._draw_rect_callback = _draw_rect_callback
        self.update()

# do the imports and replace the old FigureCanvasQT
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.FigureCanvasQT = NewFigureCanvasQT
# switch backend and setup the dark background
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
matplotlib.style.use('dark_background')

# do the plotting
plt.plot(range(9))
plt.show()
```

which produces the following picture:
[image: Result]

**EDIT**:
This seem to be fixed in release 3.3.1. [See the release notes.](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#gtk-qt-zoom-rectangle-now-black-and-white)

Comment: Thanks for your example but I can't get it to work unfortunately (tried Windows and OS-X). On OS-X I get the warning: _This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

The backend was *originally* set to 'agg' by the following code:
  File "answer1.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import FigureCanvasQT_. On Windows I just get a black back ground.

Comment: @titusjan Which python version are you using? I'm running this on Windows 10, Python 3.7.6 and matplotlib 3.2.1, and still works.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.7.6 and Matlplotlib 3.1.3.

Comment: @titusjan I tried my code with Anaconda and Spyder, and it didn't work: it just didn't do anything .I'm not sure yet why it's failing. Have you tried it with regular Python environment?

Comment: It was on windows so I think I ran it from PyCharm, not from the command line. I don't have my windows laptop at the moment, I can test later. I just tried it on OS-X and there it works fine, both from the command line and from PyCharm. I never use Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

For matplotlib 2.1.1 (installed using `apt-get install python-matplotlib` on Ubuntu 18.04), the answer by Peter does not work on the verison.
Hope it will helps someone with legacy system.

Instead, I managed to patch as following:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import matplotlib
try:
    matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
except ValueError:
    pass
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## NOTE: Override paintEvent method to bolden zoom rectangle and change its color to red.
def paintEvent(caller, _e):
    """Copy the image from the Agg canvas to the qt.drawable.

    In Qt, all drawing should be done inside of here when a widget is
    shown onscreen.
    """
    # if there is a pending draw, run it now as we need the updated render
    # to paint the widget
    if caller._agg_draw_pending:
        try:
            caller.__draw_idle_agg()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    # As described in __init__ above, we need to be careful in cases with
    # mixed resolution displays if dpi_ratio is changing between painting
    # events.
    if caller._dpi_ratio != caller._dpi_ratio_prev:
        # We need to update the figure DPI
        caller._update_figure_dpi()
        caller._dpi_ratio_prev = caller._dpi_ratio
        # The easiest way to resize the canvas is to emit a resizeEvent
        # since we implement all the logic for resizing the canvas for
        # that event.
        event = QtGui.QResizeEvent(caller.size(), caller.size())
        # We use caller.resizeEvent here instead of QApplication.postEvent
        # since the latter doesn't guarantee that the event will be emitted
        # straight away, and this causes visual delays in the changes.
        caller.resizeEvent(event)
        # resizeEvent triggers a paintEvent itself, so we exit this one.
        return

    # if the canvas does not have a renderer, then give up and wait for
    # FigureCanvasAgg.draw(caller) to be called
    if not hasattr(caller, 'renderer'):
        return

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(caller)

    if caller._bbox_queue:
        bbox_queue = caller._bbox_queue
    else:
        painter.eraseRect(caller.rect())
        bbox_queue = [
            matplotlib.transforms.Bbox(
                [[0, 0], [caller.renderer.width, caller.renderer.height]])]
    caller._bbox_queue = []
    for bbox in bbox_queue:
        l, b, r, t = map(int, bbox.extents)
        w = r - l
        h = t - b
        reg = caller.copy_from_bbox(bbox)
        buf = reg.to_string_argb()
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(buf, w, h, QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        if hasattr(qimage, 'setDevicePixelRatio'):
            # Not available on Qt4 or some older Qt5.
            qimage.setDevicePixelRatio(caller._dpi_ratio)
        origin = QtCore.QPoint(l, caller.renderer.height - t)
        painter.drawImage(origin / caller._dpi_ratio, qimage)
        # Adjust the buf reference count to work around a memory
        # leak bug in QImage under PySide on Python 3.
        import six
        if matplotlib.backends.qt_compat.QT_API == 'PySide' and six.PY3:
            import ctypes
            ctypes.c_long.from_address(id(buf)).value = 1

    # draw the zoom rectangle to the QPainter
    if caller._drawRect is not None:
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 3 / caller._dpi_ratio,
                         QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        x, y, w, h = caller._drawRect
        painter.drawRect(x, y, w, h)

    painter.end()

# Use custom figure canvas to override zoom rectangle visual
matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAggBase.paintEvent = paintEvent
```